# Secure way to update a remote database using a java client

Tags: database, post, jdbc, get

**Language : JAVA
Target-OS : Cross Platform**

I have a database on my server. I can think of few ways to update the database.

1. Making a remote database connection using the JDBC driver.
2. Using a server side script to update the database and call it using a GET or POST.

Q1. I think 1st option may be a high security risk and there is a possibility of endangering the whole database. Am I right?

Q2. Is the 2nd way better for the task or are there other ways around.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found the answer, Seems it is the second option. Awake SQL (mentioned by Pavan Kumar ) also seems to be connecting to a server side web service layer. Read this.
[How do you handle database security from a desktop application?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/150529)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the open source framework named "Awake SQL". It's based on HTTP. You can go with the first option. [click here](http://java.dzone.com/announcements/awake-sql-access-remote-sql)